# Is there any way to inherit Xaml in dotnet Maui

Tags: xaml, inheritance, layout, maui

Basically what I'm trying is, I want to have a Control that is visible on All Pages. This I'm trying to achieve by having a BasePage, from which all my Pages inherit.

BasePage.xaml

```
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,80">
         <!-- Grid.Row 0 would be the content of the Pages -->
         <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Button"/>
    </Grid>
```

In this example the Button would be globally visible on all pages that inherit from this BasePage. Only row 0 of the grid should be filled with the content of these pages.

I've tried to achieve this in the code behind, where I would create a new grid and the button and then add the content of the page to the grid. Which looks like this:

```cs
        View content = this.Content;
        Grid g = new Grid();
        g.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection()
        {
            new RowDefinition(GridLength.Star),
            new RowDefinition(new GridLength(80))
        };
        g.Add(content, 0, 0);

        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "button";
        g.Add(b, 0, 1);

        this.Content = g;
```

But this doesn't really work, as it causes multiple problems in the styling of the pages. In my case for example, the textwrapping of my labels wasn't working anymore. Can this be achieved in any way?

Mainpage.xaml:

```xml
<views:BasePage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:foo.Views"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:foo.ViewModels"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:foo.Converters"
             x:Class="foo.MainPage"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             Title="foo"
             Loaded="ContentPage_Loaded">

    <views:BasePage.Content>
         <Grid>
         <!-- Page content -->
         </Grid>
    </views:BasePage.Content>


</views:BasePage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I misunderstand your request? I have created a new project. There are two pages in it. One is the BasePage and the other is the ChildPage inherited from the BasePage.

The ChildPage has its own content in the grid's first row and the button in the grid's second row which is inherited from the BasePage.

The BasePage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Testinherit.BasePage">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,80">
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Click Me"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The ChildPage.xaml:

```
<base:BasePage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               xmlns:base="clr-namespace:Testinherit"
             x:Class="Testinherit.ChildPage"
             Title="ChildPage">
   
</base:BasePage>
```

And the ChildPage.cs:

```
public partial class ChildPage : BasePage
{
      public ChildPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
            var grid = this.Content as Grid;
            VerticalStackLayout stacklayout = new VerticalStackLayout();
            Label label = new Label() { Text = "this is a new Label in the child page"};
            Button button = new Button() { Text = "this is a new Button in the child page" };
            stacklayout.Children.Add(label);
            stacklayout.Children.Add(button);
            grid.Insert(0, stacklayout);
      }
}
```

You can change the **VerticalStackLayout** to the **Grid** in the constructor. In the code you provided, you want to put the parent page's content into the child page's grid. That's impossible. **The childpage is based on the basepage. The root view in the childpage is the grid in the basepage. You can't put the root view in a new view but you can put the new view into the root view.**

And the result picture of my project:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! that really helped. I used a ContentView so I could write the pagelayout of the childpages in xaml instead of C#.